# Error: (admin.E035) The value of 'readonly_fields[0]' is not a callable

Tags: python-3.x, django

**Summarize the problem**

```
<class 'news.admin.NewsAdmin'>: (admin.E035) The value of 'readonly_fields[0]' is not a callable, an attribut
e of 'NewsAdmin', or an attribute of 'news.News'.
```

This all code error. I learn Django, and write code how in author. But write this error :(

**Describe what you`ve tried**

I immediately insert problem in search, but not found decision

1. I read [this](https://github.com/martinmacko47/chcemvediet/issues/129) question, but it not finished
2. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54714958/how-to-fix-not-a-callable-attribute-error-in-admin-py-in-custom-user-model-in-da) question elementary, author question not correct write variable

**Show some code**

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import News, Category


class NewsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'title', 'category', 'create_at', 'updated_at', 'is_published')
    list_display_links = ('id', 'title',)  # what be links in model
    search_fields = ('title', 'content',)
    list_editable = ('is_published',)  # redact is published in menu
    list_filter = ('is_published', 'category',)  # create table, what in be setting sorted
    fields = ('title', 'category', 'content', 'photo', 'get_photo', 'is_published', 'views',
              'create_at', 'updated_at')
    readonly_fields = ('get_photo', 'views', 'create_at', 'updated_at')


class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'title')  # displays
    list_display_links = ('id', 'title')  # links
    search_fields = ('title',)


admin.site.register(News, NewsAdmin)
admin.site.register(Category, CategoryAdmin)
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse


class News(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True)
    create_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('view_news', kwargs={"news_id": self.pk})

    def __str__(self):  # return number position model
        return self.title

    objects = models.Manager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'NEWS'
        verbose_name_plural = 'NEWS'
        ordering = ['-create_at']


class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, db_index=True, verbose_name='Title category')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('category', kwargs={"category_id": self.pk})

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'
        ordering = ['title']

    def __str__(self):  # String views. If not be this parameters, be number vice world
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've put `'get_photo'` in `NewsAdmin.read_only_fields` and it is not a model field, it's supposed to be a method or a property in either `News` or `NewsAdmin`.

You should change it to `'photo'` because `read_only_fields` only meant for fields to be non-editable.

```py
class NewsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    readonly_fields = ('photo', 'views', 'create_at', 'updated_at')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `'views'` to `list_display`.
Probably a field can't be in `read_only_fields` unless it's shown in `list_display`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).